# How to use Class as a generic type marker

Tags: java

I have my method:

```
myMethod(Class class){}
```

I want to pass to this method MyClass with all descending classes, so changed it to:

```
myMethod(Class<MyClass> class){}
```

And call is:

```
myMethod(MyOtherClassExtendingMyClass.class)
```

Then I have compiler error:

```
The method myMethod(Class<MyClass>) in the type XXX is not applicable
for the arguments (Class<MyOtherClassExtendingMyClass>)
```

How to get assured that only MyClass with all it's descending classes will be allowed as parameters of this method?

Comment: Please edit the title of the question :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an upper-bounded wildcard:

```
myMethod(Class<? extends MyClass>) {}
```

You'll probably want to capture the wildcard, too:

```
<T extends MyClass> void myMethod(Class<T> klass) {}
```

This time you can refer to `T` in the body.

Comment: +1: As detailled in JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#d5e2547

Answer (score 1):

Going by your question I think you need the followng declaration of method `myMethod` :

```
myMethod(Class<? extends MyClass> clazz)
```